# Update fails if I try and update all fields, but not if I update all but the last

Tags: c#, sql, mvvm

This works

```
   UPDATE `n2000`.`orders`
    SET `OrderType` = @OrderType, `prtID` = @prtID, `ReqRef` = @ReqRef, `DateOrdered` = @DateOrdered,
    `orderETA` = @orderETA, `DateRcvd` = @DateRcvd, `Status` = @Status, `ShipCost` = @ShipCost,
    `Duties` = @Duties, `Currency` = @Currency, `Conv` = @Conv, `Terms` = @Terms,
    `Shipping` = @Shipping, `BuyerID` = @BuyerID, `ShipTo` = @ShipTo, `Notes1` = @Notes1,
    `Notes2` = @Notes2, `Notes3` = @Notes3
    WHERE `ordID` = @ordID;
    ";
```

This does not.

```
UPDATE `n2000`.`orders`
SET `OrderType` = @OrderType, `prtID` = @prtID, `ReqRef` = @ReqRef, `DateOrdered` = @DateOrdered,
`orderETA` = @orderETA, `DateRcvd` = @DateRcvd, `Status` = @Status, `ShipCost` = @ShipCost,
`Duties` = @Duties, `Currency` = @Currency, `Conv` = @Conv, `Terms` = @Terms,
`Shipping` = @Shipping, `BuyerID` = @BuyerID, `ShipTo` = @ShipTo, `Notes1` = @Notes1,
`Notes2` = @Notes2, `Notes3` = @Notes3, `legacyID` = @legacyID
WHERE `ordID` = @ordID;
";
```

For some reason adding the last value, legacyID,  breaks the whole update and then nothing updates properly in the table. Does anyone know the reason for this? The next value in the table is a left joined value from a different table if that makes a difference. legacyID is not from a  different table.

Select call

```
            LoadTableQuery.Qry = @"
SELECT `orders`.`ordID`,
    `orders`.`OrderType`,
    p1.`Name`,
    `orders`.`prtID`,
    `orders`.`ReqRef`,
    `orders`.`DateOrdered`,
    `orders`.`orderETA`,
    `orders`.`DateRcvd`,
    `orders`.`Status`,
    `orders`.`ShipCost`,
    `orders`.`Duties`,
    `orders`.`Currency`,
    `orders`.`Conv`,
    `orders`.`Terms`,
    `orders`.`Shipping`,
    `orders`.`BuyerID`,
    `orders`.`ShipTo`,
    `orders`.`Notes2`,
    `orders`.`Notes3`,
    `orders`.`legacyID`,
    p1.`Address`,
    p1.`City`,
    p1.`StateProv`,
    p1.`PostalZip`,
    p1.`Tel`,
    p1.`Contact`,
    p1.`Email`,
    p1.`OrderTaxPc`,
    p2.`To`,
    p2.`Address`,
    p2.`City`,
    p2.`Prov`,
    p2.`PostalCode`,
    p2.`ContactTel`,
    p2.`C/O`
FROM
  `n2000`.`orders`
LEFT JOIN
  `n2000`.`prt`      AS p1
    ON  (orders.prtID = p1.prtID)
LEFT JOIN
  `n2000`.`shipto`      AS p2
    ON  (orders.ShipTo = p2.Ref)

";
```

[SQL Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlEYI.png)

UpdateTable called

```
public void UpdateTable(TableQuery query, DataTable tbl)
{
    if (query.Qry != "")
    {
        if (IsConnOpen)
        {
            try
            {
                UpdateCmd.Parameters.Clear();
                UpdateCmd.CommandText = query.Qry;
                for (int i = 0; i < query.Prms.Count; i++)
                {
                    UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter());
                    UpdateCmd.Parameters[i].ParameterName = "@" + query.Prms[i].Col;
                    UpdateCmd.Parameters[i].SourceColumn = query.Prms[i].Col;
                }
                DA.Update(tbl);
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                Msg = "Error: " + ex.Number + " " + ex.Message + " from Qry = " + query.Qry;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Msg = "Error: " + ex + " " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Msg = "Not Connected";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the data type, maybe the value in the table has one datatype but the one you are updating is complete different

Comment: also, it could be that the new value is NULL but the legacyID column doesn't allow null values.

Comment: Post your sql query where you get the values from, and the table structure.

Comment: posted it. Also I don't understand why someone would come in just to downvote the question and leave :/

Comment: Does LegacyID allow null values if not, does it have a refenrece key, maybe you are insterting a value that doesnt exist in the table

Comment: I posted the table information from Workbench

Comment: Column Legacy is varchar(45) maybe you are trying to insert a bigger value, What message does it give you in sql when you try to do the update?

Comment: no message, It's a datagrid which references an SQL database. When i try and update it , and it fails, it just simply doesn't update. Not only legacyID but the update as a whole fails.

Comment: Are you using try catch block in C# to catch the error if happens, Like what happens when you are run the update? does it blow up? or just goes to the next line ? I am puzzled to know how it's possible that it doesn't throw any exception.

Comment: You're correct, it's in a try block.

Comment: So what does the catch catches what kinda message?

Comment: Error: 0 Fatal error encountered during command execution. from Qry = UPDATE `n2000`.`orders` SET ..... ;

Comment: Create a object 
StringBuilder errorMessages = new StringBuilder();
Inside the catch block put this statement 

for (int i = 0; i < ex.Errors.Count; i++)
            {
                errorMessages.Append("Index #" + i + "\n" +
                    "Message: " + ex.Errors[i].Message + "\n" +
                    "LineNumber: " + ex.Errors[i].LineNumber + "\n" +
                    "Source: " + ex.Errors[i].Source + "\n" +
                    "Procedure: " + ex.Errors[i].Procedure + "\n");
            }
          need to display Console.WriteLine(errorMessages.ToString());

Comment: Alright, there's an issue though. 'MySqlException' does not contain a definition for 'Errors' accepting a first arguement type 'MySqlException'

Comment: Can you run the whole sql statement, the select and update in the sql db to see what error it will give,  Because I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I figured it out. The issue was that when I was selecting I missed Notes1.